# ubuntu 11.10 imagemagick missing compose operator and options

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick

I have a working rails app that uses imagemagick commands on my local mac machine.

I recently deployed this app to an Ubuntu 11.10 server, made sure to do 'sudo apt-get install imagemagick'.  However it is missing a compose operator and option that my mac install have.

> convert: unrecognized compose operator `ModulusSubtract' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/999.

and

> compare: unrecognized option `-subimage-search' @ error/compare.c/CompareImageCommand/839.

it appears my linux install of imagemagick doesnt have -compose ModulusSubtract or -subimage-search ??  Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do `convert --version` and `compare --version` give you?

The `-subimage-search` option only came in around 6.6.3-6 (see [changelogs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php)).

The `ModulusSubtract` in compose only came in 6.6.1-6, and according to that changelog it was previously named 'Subtract' and 'Add', so you can use '-compose Subtract' instead.

You might need to install a newer version yourself (repository versions of software notoriously lag behind the actual versions).

Comment: I also had to install libjpeg62-dev, libpng12-dev, libfreetype6 and libfreetype6-dev then recompile.  Before doing this I couldnt read jpg or png images, and couldn't use TTF fonts.